# My image texture getting distorted when rendering animation

Tags: rendering, uv-image-editor

when I animate it in viewport it works fine. but when rendering it become distort.
Please any solution?

[image: viewport preview]

[image: rendered image]

Answer (score 0):

Oh guys I found the solution.
The problem was with subdivision modifier.
I have turned off the subdivision modifier for viewport and turned it on for render.